# Multiple bindings were found on the class path & Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path

Tags: java, gradle

I am using Gradle as a build tool and during deployment I am facing some issues which I have mentioned below.

Gradle build task has no issues but when I deployed it on tomcat8 it shows below error.

build.gradle dependencies file is as follows:

```
dependencies {

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20090211'

    // Apache Kafka Dependencies
    compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: '2.0.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'connect-json', version: '2.0.0'

    // Office365 authentication Dependencies
    compile group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'adal4j', version: '1.6.0'
    runtime group: 'com.nimbusds', name: 'oauth2-oidc-sdk', version: '5.24.1'

    // Apache Hadoop HDFS Dependencies
    compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-hdfs', version: '2.9.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-hdfs-client', version: '2.9.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-common', version: '2.9.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hive', name: 'hive-jdbc', version: '2.3.3'

    // Spring Dependencies
    compile group: 'opensymphony', name: 'sitemesh', version: '2.4.2'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '4.3.14.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-tx', version: '4.3.14.RELEASE'

    // Mysql Connector Dependency
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.6'

    // Apache Spark Dependencies
    compile group: 'com.databricks', name: 'spark-csv_2.11', version: '1.5.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.11', version: '2.3.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.11', version: '2.3.0'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', name: 'jackson-module-scala_2.11', version: '2.8.8'

    // Apache Storm & Apache Kafka Consumer Dependencies
    compile group: 'org.apache.storm', name: 'storm-core', version: '1.2.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.storm', name: 'storm-kafka', version: '1.2.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka_2.10', version: '0.9.0.1'

    // Elasticsearch Dependencies
    compile group: 'org.elasticsearch.client', name: 'elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client', version: '6.5.2'
    compile group: 'org.elasticsearch', name: 'elasticsearch', version: '6.5.2'
    //compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.11.1'
    //compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.11.1'
    //compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12'
}
```

The error message:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/sagarjoshi/opt/tomcat-analytics/apache-tomcat-8.0.53/webapps/analytics/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/sagarjoshi/opt/tomcat-analytics/apache-tomcat-8.0.53/webapps/analytics/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.8.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/sagarjoshi/opt/tomcat-analytics/apache-tomcat-8.0.53/webapps/analytics/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.0.9.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError. 
SLF4J: See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4jDelegationLoop for more details.
17-Dec-2018 11:32:29.244 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing
 javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5352)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:755)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1730)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:434)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: You have multiple backends in your class path. Slf4j considers that a problem. Remove all but one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SLF4J API is designed to bind with one and only one underlying logging framework at a time. If more than one binding is present on the classpath, SLF4J will emit a warning, listing the location of those bindings.

When multiple bindings are available on the class path, select one and only one binding you wish to use, and remove the other bindings. For example, if you have both slf4j-simple-2.0.0-alpha2.jar and slf4j-nop-2.0.0-alpha2.jar on the class path and you wish to use the nop (no-operation) binding, then remove slf4j-simple-2.0.0-alpha2.jar from the class path.

The list of locations that SLF4J provides in this warning usually provides sufficient information to identify the dependency transitively pulling in an unwanted SLF4J binding into your project. In your project's pom.xml file, exclude this SLF4J binding when declaring the unscrupulous dependency. For example, cassandra-all version 0.8.1 declares both log4j and slf4j-log4j12 as compile-time dependencies. Thus, when you include cassandra-all as a dependency in your project, the cassandra-all declaration will cause both slf4j-log4j12.jar and log4j.jar to be pulled in as dependencies. In case you do not wish to use log4j as the the SLF4J backend, you can instruct Maven to exclude these two artifacts as shown next:

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId> org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.1</version>

    <exclusions>
      <exclusion> 
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion> 
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions> 

  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your project dependencies. Do really need so many compile dependencies? Check all APIs and use the matching scope. Probably `runtime` is often enough.

Your proejct has more than one definition for a logging API and bridging (log4 and logback with slf4j). Decide which one you want to use and declare your dependencies accordingly. Provide the configuration for the used logging API.

See [slf4j - bridges](https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) how bridging works.

If you want to identify the the projects with the offending transient dependencies, use the gradle dependency tree (see [gradle - inspecting dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/inspecting_dependencies.html))

```
gradlew dependencies
```

Probably after analyzing your dependencies, you might need to exclude some dependencies according to your runtime environmen. See [gradle - managing transient dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html) how to do this.